# Customize the marker on google map with clusters

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift3

I am using google map SDK in my application and plotting marker on selected let long and for making groups on marker i am using GMUClusterManager for adding cluster on marker, but with this i am facing an issue to change the image of marker, with if i draw a marker with GMUClusterManager then there  no option to change marker image. So any one know any other way to make groups of all markers when user zoom in map, or to change the image of maker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After creating your `GMUDefaultClusterRenderer` set its delegate I used the view controller I was working in, and then implement the GMUClusterRendererDelegate

```
let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
renderer.delegate = self
clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
```

After that you implement the `func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker)` from the protocol. This method gives you access to the marker and the data enclosed in the marker.
Use an If let statement to access the data and give the marker the iconView you want `if let markerData = marker.userData`

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to remember to mark it as an answer later @Chetansharma

Answer (score 1):

Works in Swift 5

```
class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
  var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var name: String!
  var icon: UIImage

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, icon: UIImage) {
    self.position = position
    self.name = name
    self.icon = icon
  }
}

class PrincipalViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.google_map.clear()

        let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
        let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
        let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: self.google_map, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        renderer.delegate = self
        self.clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: self.google_map, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
        self.clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)


        //insert your markers type POIItem
        //self.clusterManager.add(item)

        self.clusterManager.cluster()
    }

}

extension PrincipalViewController: GMUClusterRendererDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, markerFor object: Any) -> GMSMarker? {
        switch object {
        case let item as POIItem:

            let marker = GMSMarker()

            marker.position = item.position
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "your_custom_marker")

            return marker
        case let staticCluster as GMUStaticCluster:

            let marker = GMSMarker()

            marker.position = staticCluster.position
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "your_gruped_custom_marker")

            return marker
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension PrincipalViewController: GMUClusterManagerDelegate {
    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap clusterItem: GMUClusterItem) -> Bool {
        print("didTap clusterItem")
        return true
    }

    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {
        print("didTap cluster")
        return true
     }
}
```